# React MUI Collapse not working with ToggleButtonGroup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to tie in a MUI ToggleButtonGroup with Collapse in React.

It works from the initial state to show, but it wont hide again when the hide option is selected

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import React from "react";
import ToggleButton from "@material-ui/lab/ToggleButton";
import ToggleButtonGroup from "@material-ui/lab/ToggleButtonGroup";
import Collapse from "@material-ui/core/Collapse";

export default function ToggleButtons() {
  const [showBox, setShowBox] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <ToggleButtonGroup
        value={showBox}
        exclusive
        onChange={(_, value: boolean) => setShowBox(value)}
      >
        <ToggleButton value="true">Show</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="false">Hide</ToggleButton>
      </ToggleButtonGroup>

      {showBox}

      <Collapse in={showBox}>Box is shown</Collapse>
    </>
  );
}
```

Code sand box here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ugspu?file=/demo.tsx

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the value should be boolean not string

```
<ToggleButton value={true}>Show</ToggleButton>
```

see here

[image: Edit new]

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is that your `value` in the `ToggleButton` is a string and not boolean. You may try to change it into

```
 <ToggleButton value={true}>Show</ToggleButton>
 <ToggleButton value={false}>Hide</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: Right answer but Yoel beat you to it.
Thanks for the help anyway :)